# Generating function of $\frac{h(x)}{(1-x)^2}$

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

> If $h(x)$ is the generating function for $a_r$, what is the generating function of $$\frac{h(x)}{(1-x)^2}$$

Let $h(x)$ be written as

$$h(x) = \sum_{r} a_r x^r $$

Consider more simply

$$\frac{h(x)}{1-x} = \frac{1}{1-x} h(x) =\sum_{r} x^r \sum_{r} a_r x^r$$

I tried to expand this and see what I could get

$$(1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots+x^r+\dots)(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\dots+a_rx^r+\dots)$$

there are two ways to simplify the product, either

$$a_0(1+x+x^2+\dots)+a_1(x+x^2+x^3+\dots)+ a_2(x^2+x^3+x^4+\dots)+\dots= \sum_ra_r\sum_{k\ge r}x^k$$

or
$$a_0 + (a_0+a_1)x+(a_0+a_1+a_2)x^2+(a_0+a_1+a_2+a_3)x^3 = \sum_r \left(\sum_{k\le r}a_k \right)x^r$$

obviously this is only for one factor of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ but I assume If I can get help for this I can extend it to two factors.

I'm not sure what form the answer is expected to be in? Because I could say the generating function is

$$\frac{h(x)}{1-x} = h\left(\sum_{k \ge r}x^k\right)$$

but I'm not sure that makes any sense. I was expecting to say something like

$$\frac{h(x)}{1-x} \mapsto h(x^2)$$

(the $x^2$ is not intentional, just some idea of what I believe the answer could look like)

Any help for the case of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ would be great and then I could extend it to $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$

Comment: I think that the question must be "What sequence is $h(x)/(1-x)^2$ the generating functin of?"

Comment: It probably helps a lot to note that because $\frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{1-x} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$, by taking the derivative of the geometric series we get $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)x^n$.  Then you can just use one convolution of this series with the generating function for $h(x)$.

Comment: @Somos I'm not sure, you might be right. This is from a list of review questions for my combinatorics exam, see here a screenshot from the paper [link](https://imgur.com/a/PlfkpA8)

Comment: @RobertShore I have not heard the term convolution in my class but I assume you mean a new generating function where the coefficients $c_n = a_0b_n+a_1b_{n-1}+\dots+a_{n-1}b_1+a_nb_0$ ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm talking about.

Comment: @RobertShore So then I just say the generating function of $\frac{h(x)}{(1-x)^2} = \sum_n \sum_{k \le n} (k+1)a_{n-k}x^n$ ?

Comment: That looks right, but I haven't carefully checked the limits on the sum.

Comment: @RobertShore Well i greatly appreciate the help, and if you decide to come back and check, feel free to post it as an answer so we can call this question closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note that

$$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{1-x}=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}.$$

Thus, taking the derivative of the power series we have:

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1)x^k.$$

Let

$$h(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n.$$

Then taking the convolution of these two series, we have:

$$\frac{h(x)}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n (k+1)a_{(n-k)}x^n.$$

Answer (score 1):

Another way.

Since
$(1-x)^2 = 1-2x+x^2$,
if
$\dfrac{h(x)}{(1-x)^2}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$
then

$\begin{array}\\
h(x)
&=(1-x)^2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n\\
&=(1-2x+x^2)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n-2x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n+x^2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 2a_nx^{n+1}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^{n+2}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2a_{n-1}x^{n}+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_{n-2}x^{n}\\
&=a_0+a_1x+\sum_{n=}^{\infty} a_nx^n-2a_0x-\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} 2a_{n-1}x^{n}+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} a_{n-2}x^{n}\\
&=a_0+(a_1-2a_0)x+\sum_{n=}^{\infty} (a_n-2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2})x^n\\
\end{array}a_n
$

If
$h(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} h_nx^n$
then,
equating coefficients,
$h_0 = a_0$,
$h_1 = a_1-2a_0$,
so
$a_1 
= h_1+2a_0
= h_1+2h_0
$,
and,
for $n \ge 2$,
$h_n
=a_n-2a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}
$
so
$a_n
=h_n+2a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}
$.

The advantage of this method
is that getting each new $a_n$
takes only
3 operations
(multiply, add, subtract)
instead of $n$.